# Howto tag all files of a repo (they are already commited)

Tags: git, tags

ahead info: I did forget to tag my first completed version of files and continued with changes. They are not yet added and I don't want to loose them ;-)

My approach was: clone the repo, now I have the perfect situation of my old files. "git tag" will only create the tag, but not assign it to the files. Assigning is done with the hashes, but it is hard to find out the last commit for each file to do it. Doing a "git tag -a *" will do it for all submits of all times, right?

Howto do it best?

Comment: can you give more information on what you intend to do when you say "tag the files" ?

Comment: Guess my kind of thinking was wrong ;-). For me the meaning of a tag is the possibility to checkout a certain set of files in a certain state and i still mingle the view on files with the view on commits ;-)

This said I suggest now, that a "git tag mytag" would tag the last state of all files in HEAD, though the last commit only changed one file, right?

Answer (score 0):

1. Re-read docs about [tagging in Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)
2. Forget about "files" concept in most use-cases of Git, changeset ("all files in repo in some historical state") is the fundamental basics of (all) VCSes a lot of years
3. You can skip totally unnecessary clone step and just [tag needed changeset](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_tagging_later) at any time later after its creation

Comment: "*all files in repo in some historical state*" This is **snapshot**, not changeset AFAIK.

Comment: yes, that helped me @Lazy Badger, I also understanf now, that clone was waste ;-). It's solved! :-)